# Android BottomSheetDialogFragment data changes the data in parent Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, bottomsheetdialogfragment

**Problem Statement**
I have a problem of data being changed in fragment whenever the data is modified in the `BottomSheetDialogFragment`

**App Description**
In my app I have the MainActivity which host 2 Fragment in it's ViewPager. 1st Fragment for app content and 2nd Fragment (let's call it `GalleryFragment`) that shows the gallery view. User can tap on gallery item which loads up the BottomSheet (let's call it `GalleryBottomSheet`) - that hosts RecyclerView to show gallery item in full screen. Now initially app feeds the `GalleryFragment` with the `ArrayList` to show the gallery items. When user clicks on  the Gallery item, this `ArrayList` is passed to the `GalleryBottomSheet`.

**So What's Happening**
What's happening is whenever I am removing an item from the `ArrayList` in my `GalleryBottomSheet`, It automatically also remove that item in the `ArrayList` of `GalleryFragment`. In short, Any update in the `Arraylist` from `GalleryBottomSheet` impacting the `ArrayList` in `GalleryFragment`

**What do you want**
I want seperation of concerns. I don't want the change made in the `ArrayList` of `GalleryBottomSheet` to impact the original `ArrayList` of `GalleryFragment`

**Show me the damn code**
To make this question concise, I am adding only the important part of the code.

~ *GalleryFragment.java*

```
    public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {

        private RecyclerView recyclerView;
        private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>(); //This is the one which will be passed to the GalleryBottomSheet
        private GalleryAdapter galleryAdapter;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);

            //setting up all the UI work...

            arrayList = FindFiles(); //FindFiles is a private function searching for all file in the dir and adding the path as a string to the arraylist
            galleryAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getActivity()); //init the adapter
            recyclerView.setAdapter(galleryAdapter); //setting the adapter

            return view;
        }
    }

    private class GalleryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        private final Activity activity;


        GalleryAdapter(Activity context) {
            this.activity = context;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.gallery_content_item, parent, false);
            return new ItemViewHolder(view);
            

        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
            if(holder instanceof ItemViewHolder){
               //setting up stuff..
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return arrayList.size();
        }



        private class ItemViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
            ImageView imageView;
            ItemViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArrayList("list", arrayList);

                GalleryBottomSheet galleryBottomSheet= GalleryBottomSheet.newInstance();
                galleryBottomSheet.setOnRefreshListener( new GalleryBottomSheet.GalleryInterface() {
                    @Override
                    public void onRefresh() {
                        //here the actual arrayList size reduced even though the arrayList that was modified exist in GalleryBottomSheet
                        System.out.println("CURRENT LIST SIZE: " + arrayList.size());
                    }
                });
                galleryBottomSheet.setArguments(bundle);
                galleryBottomSheet.show(getParentFragmentManager(), "galleryPager");

                
            }



    }
```

~ *GalleryBottomSheet.java*

```
public class GalleryBottomSheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

    static GalleryBottomSheet newInstance() {
        return new GalleryBottomSheet();
    }

    public interface GalleryInterface {
        void onRefresh();
    }

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ViewAdapter viewAdapter;
    private Button deleteBtn;
    private GalleryInterface galleryInterface;

    public void setOnRefreshListener( GalleryInterface galleryInterface){
        this.galleryInterface = galleryInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //.. setting up sheetDialog
        return bottomSheetDialog;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(BottomSheetDialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, R.style.GalleryBottomStyle);
    }

   @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_sheet, container, false);

        Bundle bundle = getArguments();
        ArrayList<String> filePathArr = bundle.getStringArrayList("list"); //here arrayList from GalleryFragment
        
        //Setting up all UI views...

        deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int positionPager = recyclerView.computeVerticalScrollOffset(); //just for demo, in the actual app we are using addOnScrollListener for position
                filePathArr.remove(positionPager);
                viewAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(positionPager);
                galleryInterface.onRefresh(); //this is where GalleryFragment shows that the arraylist is modified too.
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Deleted Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        
        return view;
    }


    //setting up viewAdapter and other stuff


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out the main problem is that object is stored in memory by reference. By modifying the arrayList from `GalleryBottomSheet` it also changes the original arrayList since the exact arrayList was referred in `GalleryBottomSheet` from `GalleryFragment`. The solution is to simply initializing a new ArrayList in `GalleryBottomSheet`

Changing from:

```
ArrayList<String> filePathArr = bundle.getStringArrayList("list");
```

to:

```
ArrayList<String> filePathArr = new ArrayList<>(bundle.getStringArrayList("list"));
```